# Regex to retrieve the ticket number from data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a survey result dataset and need to extract ticket number for one of the answers.

Data

```
               survey  question   response
               S1         Q10       A2345677Public
               S1         Q10       https://tt.test.com/V123456
               S1         Q10       [V987657]
```

I need to data to be

```
              survey  question   response
               S1         Q10       A2345677
               S1         Q10       V123456
               S1         Q10       V987657
```

Regex I used and not working -:

```
              regexp_substr(response,'/[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
```

Comment: None of your examples has digits followed by alphabetics. What's the actual format here?

Comment: Your regex is saying "0+ letters, followed by 1+ digit, followed by 0+ letters/digits". Do you actually want it to say "One letter followed only by digits"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is "dirty" in different ways without structure (A2345677Public, https://tt.test.com/V123456, [V987657]), it is not possible to solve this with a regex. For example your regex would match 'Public' too in the first example.